# Avoid REQUEST_INSTALL_PERMISSION via Cordova File Opener 2

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

My Ionic Android app is being rejected by android play store due to REQUEST_INSTALL_PERMISSION.
When I search in Android Studio, it shows the persmission is asked by Cordova File Opener 2 plugin.

I have tried multiple solution to avoid this permission.

1. Manually removing it from manifest file after building the ionic project.
2. using permission tool:remove="true" in manifest.

But nothing works.
My app is still being rejected by android play store.

Does any one has the solution to this problem?